# primefaces P:layout not working at all

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I used primefaces showcase example,
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutElement.jsf
 but it is not displaying anything.

My Page is:

```
<h:head>
<title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40"
        maxSize="200">  
    Left  
</p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
    Center  
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far for others to look at and help you out.

Comment: Hi Ravi.. I have edited the question to include the code on my page. This code just creates a square and it doesn't print left and center words in respective sections

Comment: Strange, I am able to see them. Can you open the Developer tools of your browser and see if the text is present. And if possible post the screen shot of the html markup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weird, its totally working for me . are you using the right namespaces for your tags and doctype?
like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya It worked! I found I was missing jsf core  and jstl core tag libraries.

Comment: @Amruta and i dont think you need jstl tag as i can see from your code, you are not using any jstl. :)